# Write $\mathbb P(X+Y \leq c \mid X=d)$ in terms of $f$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

**Problem:** Let $X,Y$ random variables with joint pdf $f(x,y)$. Write $\mathbb P(X+Y \leq c \mid X=d)$ in terms of $f$.

**Attempt:** I have problems with this kind of things:

$$\mathbb P(X+Y \leq c \mid X=d) = \frac {\mathbb P (X+Y \leq c , X=d) }{ f_X(d)} = \frac {\int_{-\infty}^{c-d} f_Y(t) \, dt}{ f_X(d)}.$$

Why is it wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Generally speaking, whenever you have a PDF (in this case $f_X(d)$) outside of an integral in an equation of probabilities, you are wrong. There are a few (rare) cases where this can be considered correct, but this is not one of them.

Comment: @Dfrtbx I don't understand why we just substitute the value and drop the conditioning, as in the answer of Mostafa Ayaza.

Comment: Well, since it's their answer, you should ask them. But my answer is: If you had a weaker condition, say $X \le d,$ rather than $X = d,$ then you wouldn't be able to substitute in this case, because $X$ is still random. But if we know $X=d,$ then $X$ is deterministic, so we can just as well consider it a constant.

Comment: Your first equal sign in the question implies that $f_X(d)=1$ if $\Bbb P(X+Y \leq c \mid X = d)\neq 0$, which has no reason to be true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even simpler! $$\Bbb P(X+Y \leq c \mid X=d)=\Bbb P(d+Y \leq c )=\Bbb P(Y \leq c-d)=\int_{-\infty}^{c-d}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,y) \, dx \, dy$$

Comment: It is exactely as the first equality here, I don't get the point!